# How to list all the functions signatures in an R file?

Tags: r

Is there an R function that lists all the functions in an R script file along with their arguments?

i.e. an output of the form:

```
func1(var1, var2)
func2(var4, var10)
.
.
.
func10(varA, varB)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Please refer to the answer by @Konrad Rudolph instead

You can create a new environment, source your file in that environment and then list the functions in it using lsf.str() e.g.

```
test.env <- new.env()
sys.source("myfile.R", envir = test.env)
lsf.str(envir=test.env)
rm(test.env)
```

or if you want to wrap it as a function:

```
listFunctions <- function(filename) {
  temp.env <- new.env()
  sys.source(filename, envir = temp.env)
  functions <- lsf.str(envir=temp.env)
  rm(temp.env)
  return(functions)
}
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer. Pls see the answer by @Konrad Rudolph https://stackoverflow.com/a/31211194/1389469

Comment: Great answer! Following!

Answer (score 13):

Using [`sys.`]`source` has the very undesirable side-effect of executing the source inside the file. At the worst this has security problems, but even “benign” code may simply have unintended side-effects when executed. At best it just takes unnecessary time (and potentially *a lot*).

It’s actually unnecessary to execute the code, though: it is enough to *parse* it, and then do some syntactical analysis.

The actual code is trivial:

```
file_parsed = parse(filename)
functions = Filter(is_function, file_parsed)
function_names = unlist(Map(function_name, functions))
```

And there you go, `function_names` contains a vector of function names. Extending this to also list the function arguments is left as an exercise to the reader. Hint: there are two approaches. One is to `eval` the function definition (now that we know it’s a function definition, this is safe); the other is to “cheat” and just get the list of arguments to the `function` call.

The implementation of the functions used above is also not particularly hard. There’s probably even something already in R core packages (‘utils’ has a lot of stuff) but since I’m not very familiar with this, I’ve just written them myself:

```
is_function = function (expr) {
    if (! is_assign(expr)) return(FALSE)
    value = expr[[3L]]
    is.call(value) && as.character(value[[1L]]) == 'function'
}

function_name = function (expr) {
    as.character(expr[[2L]])
}

is_assign = function (expr) {
    is.call(expr) && as.character(expr[[1L]]) %in% c('=', '<-', 'assign')
}
```

This correctly recognises function declarations of the forms

1. `f = function (…) …`
2. `f <- function (…) …`
3. `assign('f', function (…) …)`

It won’t work for more complex code, since assignments can be arbitrarily complex and in general are only resolvable by actually executing the code. However, the three forms above probably account for ≫ 99% of all named function definitions in practice.