# R List functions in file

Tags: r

How do I list all functions of a certain R file doing something like

```
list = list.all.functions(file.name, alphabetical = TRUE, ...)
```

where `list` is a string vector containing the names of the functions in `file.name`?

The solution of [How to list all the functions and their arguments in an R file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259681/how-to-list-all-the-functions-and-their-arguments-in-an-r-file/20260081#20260081) gives no output for me (since I am not interested in arguments I opened a new question).

**EDIT**

File `allometry.R` starts with

```
#==========================================================================================#
#==========================================================================================#
#    Standing volume of a tree.                                                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
dbh2vol <<- function(hgt,dbh,ipft){
   vol  = pft$b1Vol[ipft] * hgt * dbh ^ pft$b2Vol[ipft]
   return(vol)
}#end function dbh2ca
#==========================================================================================#
#==========================================================================================#
```

My main looks like

```
rm(list=ls())

here     = "/directory/of/allometry.R/"
setwd(here)

is_function = function (expr) {
  if (! is_assign(expr))
    return(FALSE)
  value = expr[[3]]
  is.call(value) && as.character(value[[1]]) == 'function'
}

function_name = function (expr)
  as.character(expr[[2]])

is_assign = function (expr)
  is.call(expr) && as.character(expr[[1]]) %in% c('=', '<-', 'assign')


file_parsed = parse("allometry.R")
functions = Filter(is_function, file_parsed)
function_names = unlist(Map(function_name, functions))
```

Comment: Did _both_ answers fail for you?  I find that unlikely.

Comment: I tried both, I get no output

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample of the file whose functions you are trying to list?

Comment: Yes sure. In my edit I've put an almost reproducible example. In the specific case printing the last variable `function_names` gives NULL as a result.

Comment: Just change `<<-` to `<-` in our `allometry.R` input file (or add `<<-` to the vector `c('=', ...` but 99.9% chance that you do not need such global declarations. They are nearly always a bad coding style)

Comment: Ok got it. It was actually the global equality <<- instead of =

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late to join the party, but better late than never.

There is a package called `NCmisc` which has a function to list all functions in a file and returns a list where the names of the components are the names of the packages they belong to. If there are any functions in the global environment, they will be under the `.GobalEnv` list component. Simply load all packages the file uses and then run the following:

```
all.functions <- list.functions.in.file(
                       filename = "/path/to/file/my_file.R")
```