# R: function to return function interface

Tags: r, io, higher-order-functions

Is there in R an utility to process a function interface? For example say I have a file `operators.R` where I define many functions like

```
fun1 = function(x,y,...){
body(x,y)
}

fun2 = function(w,...){
body(w,z)
return z
}

...
```

In a second file I read the functions contained in `operators` ([R List functions in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815780/r-list-functions-in-file)) and store their names in a string vector like

```
function_names = "fun1" "fun2" ...
```

and then use them by sourcing `operators.R` and doing

```
myf = get(function_names[2])
new_variable = myf(x= 1, y=2)
```

However I would like to be able to retrieve the expected I/O of the different functions. So having something like

```
myf = get(function_names[1])
my_input = f_input(myf)

print(my_input)
> "x" "y"
```

And similarly for the output.

Comment: Are you just asking for `args()`?

Comment: Or `formals()`, more specifically `names(formals(myf))` ?

Comment: Did not expect that to be so simple. `names(formals(myf))` is perfect for the input, is there a similar tool for the return value?