# Is there a way to always check for a function within one specific package before looking through the rest of the search path?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm working on writing an R package that masks several functions from various tidyverse packages. For my package to work correctly, I need the masked functions within it to ALWAYS be called over the functions from tidyverse. Because of the way the package is designed, just using `my_package::function` will NOT work for solving this problem.

Is there a way to force a package to always be second in the `search()` path? If not, is there a way to block specific functions from being run when my package is installed (for instance, is there somewhere I can write in my package that `readr::read_csv` should never be used over my masked `read_csv`?).

Comment: If such a method exists it sounds like it would be antagonistic to the user. They should always remain in control of the their search path and be allowed to call any function they like so you can't really enforce it. Perhaps a more specific example of what you are really trying to accomplish would be useful to give you better advice.

Comment: The package I'm working on is attempting to analyze the project files (.R and .Rmd) that users write and provide them with reports containing information about certain functions they use (set.seed, library, read_csv, etc) to give a report on reproducibility. The way it does this is by rendering all of the files in a user's directory and logging all of the functions that are used. The functions that get logged are the ones I mask manually. The problem is that, if the original package is earlier in the search path, it won't find my masked function and won't log that the function was used.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't other approaches that don't require masking functions? For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20259681/324364)?

Comment: I hadn’t looked into any yet. That might be a good approach to look into, but would require a pretty complete restructuring of the package (which someone else wrote and i’m just editing, so i’d prefer to work with the skeleton that already exists). Definitely useful, though. Thanks!